# Gutenberg link of internal page not showing

Tags: block-editor

I'm trying to add a link to my gutenberg paragraph.

But when I try to add an internal link, the suggestion isn't showing the desired page (or the desired article), but it's working well for my custom post type.

I've wordpress 5.5

Thanks for helping me

Comment: When you search for something, it fires an async request to WP API. Can you check browser console if there is any error?

Comment: I have a statut 200, but the json is empty. I had to correct this line in wp-admin/includes/class-wp-screen.php `$id = isset($GLOBALS['hook_suffix']) ? $GLOBALS['hook_suffix'] : "";` because it triggered an error on a lot of my pages, is there a link between that ?